# Asymmetric cryptography and JWT

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jwt

I'm trying to understand how JWT is implemented in a codebase that I'm reviewing. I read [this](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/asymmetric-cryptography) and [this](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/asymmetric-cryptography)

However, it seems in this codebase, the client has the private AND public key... It has the public key of the server and its own private key (I assume the server has the corresponding private key). Why is this necessary? Shouldn't the client only need the public key and the server only needs the private key? If the client is encrypting a message, can't it use the public key to encrypt it and the server just needs the private key to decrypt it? Conversely, can't it decrypt encrypted messages from the server with its public key? Why would the client need two sets of public and private keys?

From the reading:

> To create a digital signature, signing software (such as an email program) creates a one-way hash of the electronic data to be signed. The user's private key is then used to encrypt the hash, returning a value that is unique to the hashed data. The encrypted hash, along with other information such as the hashing algorithm, forms the digital signature. Any change in the data, even to a single bit, results in a different hash value. This attribute enables others to validate the integrity of the data by using the signer's public key to decrypt the hash. If the decrypted hash matches a second computed hash of the same data, it proves that the data hasn't changed since it was signed.

1. What is the differnce between the hashed data and encrypted data? Why do you need to hash it first? Are hashed data encrypted?
2. Where doe that secon computed hash come from? If the decryptor is attempting to apply the public key to the encrypted data... how does it know it succeeded? What does it compare it to? Where does that comparison hash come from?

Comment: Great question, well, actually 12 questions in one. A bit too broad for StackOverflow IMO

Comment: :(. Please? I'll accept a long rambly answer?

Comment: Generally speaking, why are broad questions not acceptable on a place like StackOverflow? What harm is there asking questions that are broad? Shouldn't SO ultimately be a place for information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JWT is signed (not encrypted) with the private key of the sender. jWT content can be encrypted optionally using JWE.

A symmetric key is used to sign and verify. With an asymmetric key pair, the message is signed with private key and verified with the public.

A digital signature protects the message against alterations and identify the sender. An asymmetric key allows the receiver to verify the signature using sender's public key without compromise the private key

JWT signing can be used both in client or server side depending on the purpose. For example, in an authentication flow

- **client side**:  API requests, where the server validates signature with public key uploaded during registration
- **server side**: issue tokens to final users after presenting credentials

Internally, a digital signature involves several cryptographic operations, digest the message, encrypt the hash and add the algorithm identifier. But you do not have to worry about this because all programming languages ​​support it

I tried to explain JWT&digital signatures in a general way instead of answering your specific questions. I probably have left some. Please comment

Comment: When would the sender and receiver have two sets of private and public keys? In the current code that I'm reviewing, the client has both a public key and a separate private key. So I assume the server has the corresponding public and private keys. There are two sets of keys being used.

Comment: Could you post the link of that code or explain what is its general purpose?

Comment: Without seeing the code it is difficult to know what the purpose is, but if the client and server have a pair of asymmetric keys they probably want to do mutual authentication through digital signature. RSA keys can be used also to exchange a symmetric encryption key, but in this keys is just needed the public key of one party